# html force files to download (not open in browser)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, download

I want the music link to be downloaded

But all phone browsers open it and play it inside

Used the download tag but still failed

```
 <a title=" dowload music " href="<?php echo get_field("post_link_low") ?>" download="true">
  <img width="20px" height="20px" src="/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/dowload.png" alt=" dowload music">
  dowload music
</a>
```

Comment: Does the href link point to a file within the same website? If not then the download attribute has no effect (this is documented). Also, you mention phone browsers - are you saying it works as expected on all desktop browsers?

Comment: I have two types of links
One is inside this site: "https://98diha.ir"
Another download host: "http://dl.98diha.ir/" 

But none of it works.
But I saw sites that can be downloaded in the same way.
Now, What can I do now so that the phone does not open in the browser?
- There is no problem in the desktop browser.